# C# very simple keyboard hook

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, hook, keyboard-hook

im trying to create a custom macro program in C# and I want to know how I can create a low level keyboard hook. I have looked around and have found some but i do not understand how they work or how i can customise it :/

can anyone show me how I can create a keyboard hook that basically does:

**once any key is pressed, the int keycode is set to a method (i think the VK code is what i need?)**

the exampels i find online seem too complicated for that :/

Thanks :)

Comment: Which ones have you found already?

Comment: I have found http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: and a few on SO but they seem too complicated :/

Comment: The MSDN example seems straightforward -- I can't see how to make it much simpler.  Have you tried using that as a starting point?  Or just compiling it to see how it works?

Comment: I tried compiling it but it just shows an empty cmd box and disappears :/

Comment: Yeah, this question gets asked twice a week. The two samples that have been posted work fine, if you follow the instructions exactly. It's not going to get very simple; a low-level hook is a complicated thing by nature, and it's really not used all that often.

Comment: possible duplicate of [spy keyboard (how to get keyboard digets via C# win forms app)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815945/spy-keyboard-how-to-get-keyboard-digets-via-c-win-forms-app)

Comment: @Ozzy: Just noticed that you mentioned you were trying to do this from a console app. I think the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776664/c-low-level-keyboard-hook-not-working) solves your problem. The examples you've been finding on the web assume you're doing it from a WinForms application, not a Console app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A Simple C# Global Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx) on CodeProject seems about right. It was the second hit on Google when I searched for 'keyboard hook' and the first when I searched for your exact title. 
Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a RAW INPUT example on code project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297312/Minimal-Key-Logger-using-RAWINPUT), it may be helpful as a starting point.