# Intercepting and modifying keyboard input at a message queue level

Tags: c#, .net

Lately I was playing with Windows native functions `RegisterHotKey` and `SendInput`, trying to change `Y` into `Z` and similar. I know this is not the best way to modify keyboard input, it is just an exercise. It worked well for swapping 1 key for a different singular key. But then I tried something more complex.

I wanted to listen for shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> and execute <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. It didn't work as expected because I ended up with both left and right <kbd>Alt</kbd> being pressed at the same time so it did a paste command instead of `@`. The problem is that the hotkeys were also generating inputs that mixed with my synthetized input.

Can I intercept and modify the character before OS sends it to my foreground application at a deeper level?

While writing this, I found the [GetMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) function. Could I hook it to solve this problem and modify the MSG struct?

I found a working example of how to hook a similar function in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17579778/12102460), but I was unable to modify the structs that `IntPtr` was pointing to. Was I supposed to create my own struct and change pointer to point to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# very simple keyboard hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928169/c-sharp-very-simple-keyboard-hook)

Comment: @MickyD keyboard hooks look for a single key press. OP wants to translate four simultaneous key presses into an entirely different structure, so no that link does not answer the question. A hook may be the way to go though - indeed [OP linked to one in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579658/how-to-intercept-all-the-keyboard-events-and-prevent-losing-focus-in-a-winforms)